# Compare 2 cucumber JSON reports with ruby

Tags: json, ruby, cucumber

The problem is: I have 2 cucumber test reports in JSON format
I need to remove redundant key-value pairs from those reports and compare them, but I can't understand how to remove the unnecessary data from those 2 jsons because of their structure after JSON.parse (array or hash with many nested arrays/hashes). Please advice if there are some gems or known solutions to do this
JSON structure is e.g. :

```
[
  {
    "uri": "features/home_screen.feature",
    "id": "as-a-user-i-want-to-explore-home-screen",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "As a user I want to explore home screen",
    "description": "",
    "line": 2,
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@home_screen",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "elements": [
      {
        "keyword": "Background",
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "line": 3,
        "type": "background",
        "before": [
          {
            "match": {
              "location": "features/step_definitions/support/hooks.rb:1"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 505329000
            }
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "name": "I click OK button in popup",
            "line": 4,
            "match": {
              "location": "features/step_definitions/registration_steps.rb:91"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 2329140000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "And ",
            "name": "I click Allow button in popup",
            "line": 5,
            "match": {
              "location": "features/step_definitions/registration_steps.rb:96"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 1861776000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Did you look for a gems that compare json or hashes?

Comment: You might try [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) the gem I have created exactly for this kind of tasks. It allows iterating, mapping and reducing the deeply nested structures.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin interesting, will try it now, I'll keep you posted on the result

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin looks like this is exactly what I've needed, thanks a lot

Comment: @Mikhah cool, welcome.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin make an answer of your comment. so I'll be able to mark it as correct answer, you'll gain some points on stack and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking for a gem, you might try [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) I have created exactly for this kind of tasks.

It allows iterating, mapping and reducing the deeply nested structures. For instance, to filter out all the keys called `"name"` on all levels, you might do:

```
input.iteraptor.reject(/name/)
```

The more detailed description might be found on the github page linked above.